# How to delete using inner join in C-TreeACESQL?

Tags: sql, nosql

I have below query which I need to make it work in CTREESQL but no success till now:

```
delete c  
from (select col1, col2,right(rtrim(col3),1) as col3 
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2,right(rtrim(col3),1)
having COUNT(NULLIF(ltrim(col4), '')) =1 and COUNT(*)=2)d join table c on
c.col1 = d.col1 and c.col2= d.col2 and right(rtrim(c.col3),1) = d.col3
where c.col4 is not  null and LTRIM(c.col4)<>''
```

The below query works fine for select with joins:

```
select c.*  
from (select col1, col2,right(rtrim(col3),1) as col3 
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2,right(rtrim(col3),1)
having COUNT(NULLIF(ltrim(col4), '')) =1 and COUNT(*)=2)d join table c on
c.col1 = d.col1 and c.col2= d.col2 and right(rtrim(c.col3),1) = d.col3
where c.col4 is not  null and LTRIM(c.col4)<>''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle in weekend, I was able to make it work.

```
Create Table admin.dupes( col1, col2, col3 )
AS
select col1, col2,right(rtrim(col3),1) as col3 
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2,right(rtrim(col3),1)
having COUNT(NULLIF(ltrim(col4), '')) =1 and COUNT(*)=2

delete from table
where 
table.col4 is not  null and LTRIM(table.col4)<>''
and exists (select 1 from dupes d where table.col1 = d.col1 and table.col2= d.col2 and right(rtrim(table.col3),1) = d.col3
)

Drop Table admin.dupes
```

I could not use derived table/temporary table as both were not working.